# remote host terminated the handshake

Tags: java, spring, ssl, java-8, handshake

Getting this error after upgrading the JDK from `JDK1.8_131` to `JDK1.8_291` this error pop up when trying to log in.

[Error when trying to log in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iokc1.png)

On the logs I get this Error:

```
<Oct 1, 2023 11:35:29,499 AM IDT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer',5,Thread Group for Queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer']]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: Exception occurred during SSLEngine.wrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer).
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.signers.PSSSigner.generateSignature(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.PSSSignatureSpi.engineSign(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineSign(Signature.java:1382)
    at java.security.Signature.sign(Signature.java:698)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateVerify$T13CertificateVerifyMessage.<init>(CertificateVerify.java:931)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateVerify$T13CertificateVerifyProducer.onProduceCertificateVerify(CertificateVerify.java:1105)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateVerify$T13CertificateVerifyProducer.produce(CertificateVerify.java:1098)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.produce(SSLHandshake.java:420)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T13ClientHelloConsumer.goServerHello(ClientHello.java:1096)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T13ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:1032)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.onClientHello(ClientHello.java:716)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:683)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:376)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:479)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:990)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:977)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:924)
    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doTasks(JSSEFilterImpl.java:223)
    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:123)
    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.isMessageComplete(JSSEFilterImpl.java:354)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.readReadySocketOnce(SocketMuxer.java:989)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.readReadySocket(SocketMuxer.java:930)
    at weblogic.socket.NIOSocketMuxer.process(NIOSocketMuxer.java:599)
    at weblogic.socket.NIOSocketMuxer.processSockets(NIOSocketMuxer.java:563)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.run(SocketReaderRequest.java:30)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.execute(SocketReaderRequest.java:43)
    at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:147)
    at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:119)
```

I tried to replace the JDK with a higher version to work with TLS1.3 and then got this error.

Comment: Make sure any manual additions to your certs made in the older runtime are ported to the new runtime